# Typescript doesn't deep code analyze the return value of getter function

Tags: typescript

Typescript 2.9, doesn't understand the deep code analysis, it always shows me an error like this `[ts] Object is possibly 'null'.` at `this.parentElement.value`. But actually there is a check, which is through a property accessor though.

Any better way of handling things like that?

```js
class Node {

  parentElement: Node | null;

  get value() {
    return this.isRootElement ? 4 : this.parentElement.value;
  }

  get isRootElement() {
    return !this.parentElement;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.  Narrowing analysis doesn't go through functions, except possibly in a limited way if [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) is implemented.  In your example, it doesn't seem too bad to just inline the `!this.parentElement`.  Another option using a user-defined type guard, which doesn't seem worthwhile to me for this small example:

```
class Node {

  parentElement: Node | null;

  get value() {
    return !this.isNonRootElement() ? 4 : this.parentElement.value;
  }

  isNonRootElement(): this is Node & {parentElement: Node} {
    return this.parentElement != null;
  }
}
```

If you have a more complex example, please share it and people might be able to find other workarounds.